# Как сверстать такое на флексбоксах?

Tags: css

Нужны ли тут гриды? Как сверстать такое, не могу понять позиционирование[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут абсолютным позиционированием можно обойтись.

Comment: Приложить код того, что у вас уже есть. Или вы хотите, чтобы мы за вас все это сверстали?

Answer (score 0):

ну родителю задай justify-content: column;

внутри:

```
<h3>Что может быть лучше...</h3>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Прохладная</li>
        <li>Минеральная</li>
        <li>Освежающая</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- ul задай дисплей флекс -->
<div>содержимое</div>
```

А в содержимом блоки с абсолютным позиционированием. Иначе как еще их расположить полукругом.

Comment: `justify-content: column` не бывает.

Comment: Сори. Имел ввиду flex-direction: column. Спасибо что поправили.